# Copy file to a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to `shutil.copy()` function to copy file to another directory. I try to execute the following code:

```
copy(open("/home/dizpers/pytest/testfile1.txt", "r"), "/home/dizpers/pytest")
```

But python shell shows me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 116, in copy
    dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 112, in basename
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

So, I understand why this problem appears. I open the file with `open()` function. And I think that I also should **open a directory** like this. How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shutil.copy` takes in two paths, not a file object and a path, you should just specify the path instead of creating a file object for the first argument

You can use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) if you need to use a file object for the first argument, but you'll have to use a file object for the second argument as well.

Comment: The OP wants to give a directory name as destination, so using `copyfileobj()` seems more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @Sven agreed, wasn't so much recommending it as noting its existence, but edited to clarify.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
shutil.copy ("somefile.txt","otherfile.txt")
```