# How to copy an image with date in the new filename?

Tags: python, linux, image

I'm looking for a way to copy an image file from a given source with Python.

I did read several stuff on the internet but what I found was always working just on one specific platform. I would like to know if there exists a functionality in Python that would make it possible to easily copy an image file ?

My target would be to have this in the end :

1. folder/image_title.jpg
2. copying the image
3. new_folder/new_image_title.jpg

with the *new_image_title* being the date of the day.

My code looks like this at the moment :

```
import shutil
import datetime

shutil.copy('folder/alpha.jpg', 'new_folder/'datetime.date()'.jpg')
```

But I get an error: *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870177/copy-file-to-a-directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm done with it, thanks to you :)
So here is my final version, in case it could help other people :

```
import shutil
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date=str(now.year)+'-'+str(now.month)+'-'+str(now.day)

new_folder = "source/new_folder"
dest = new_folder + '/' + str(date) + '.jpg'
shutil.copy('source/alpha.jpg', dest)
```

One last thing : at the moment, the program just runs without saying anything. So does anyone knows how to print a message saying whether or not the copying did work ?

Comment: You could always check and see if the file exists locally (and is non-zero size) - check out the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module for this, and if you want display it (using the PIL) ..

Comment: So you came for help, got all the answers, and then posted and accepted your *own* question? Sheesh .. if you wanted to share your final implementation based on all the help you got you could have just updated your original post, then your answer would have been next to your question.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

You probably want a simple string for your second argument:

instead of this:

```
shutil.copy('folder/alpha.jpg', 'new_folder/'datetime.date()'.jpg')
```

try:

```
dest = new_folder + '/' + str(datetime.date(2012, 8, 19)) + '.jpg'
shutil.copy('folder/alpha.jpg', dest)
```

with:

```
new_folder = 'bla'
```

`dest` becomes:

```
    'bla/2012-08-19.jpg'
```

tweak as needed to make the name unique (add time stamp?). Also note, it's usually better to use [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) for creating new paths.

Comment: Thanks for your help Levon ! I'm actually working on Linux, and I get an error message : 
"ImportError: No module named PIL"
What I'm trying to do at the moment is just to copy a file from a folder to another folder. And have no idea how to make it look like...

Comment: @bl1nk You need to install the PIL .. it's not a standard part of the distribution. I know it exists for the Windows and Mac, you'll have to check to see if there's a Linux distribution. Also, it would be good for you to tag your post with "linux" so to make this constraint clear.

Comment: @Qnan This is just some getting started code showing the PIL and Python to grab an image from the web, OP may want to do more with the image later (or perhaps not), OP can decide. The advantage here is that they will have the image and the methods to display, manipulate it etc if need be. There are other ways to grab an image from the web too, this shows one way.

Comment: @Levon didn't say anything about that in the question, though. And copying using `shutil` is much faster that loading stuff in the memory and writing it back down

Comment: @Qnan I have no argument with you .. as I said there are also other ways to accomplish this task. Please don't try to find a reason to argue when there's none. Feel free to post your own solution if you have strong feelings on this (you already provided a link).

Comment: Thanks Levon and Qnan. I actually was working with the shutil but was getting errors (did make a mistake in the writing). Is shutil working with URLs too ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `SyntaxError` because your string forming syntax is incorrect.  Corrected, the code would look like this:

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

filename = 'folder/alpha.jpg'
target_folder = 'new_folder'

ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

shutil.copy(filename,
            os.path.join(target_folder, '%s%s'
                         % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT), ext))
```

Answer (score 0):

install [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

and run command in the photo path:

> exiftool -d "./%Y-%m-%d" "-directory